# Multibib gives wrong hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, multibib, hyperlink

I'm using multibib for my thesis. I have two bibliographies. The first one is for my publications while the second is for all the papers that I cite.

When I'm using the same style for both (\bibliographystyle{utphys}) everything works fine.
On the other hand if I'm using different style for my publications (e.g. \bibliographystylemy{alpha}) the hyperlink takes me to the title page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Slightly late welcome to the site! Could you make a small example document that shows this issue, as you did in your first question? That makes it easier for people here to reproduce the issue and to try out possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marijn,

Making an example actually solved the problem (there was no problem in my example...). I found that I need to call hyperref just before I call multibib and after I call almost all the rest of the packages. It seems to solve the problem.

Comment: That is one of the reasons we ask for minimal examples :) many times that indeed allows people to isolate and solve the problem by themselves without any further help.